# Custom prototype chain for a function

Tags: javascript, prototype, ecmascript-5

I am just curious whether I can include an object into function prototype chain. What I mean:

```
var test = function() { return 'a'; };

console.log(test.bind(this)); // return new bound function

// changing the prototype
// in console the prototype is really set as needed
// test => new object => function prototype => Object prototype
var F = function() {};
F.prototype = Function.prototype;
test.prototype = new F();

console.log(test.bind()); // this still works and returns new bound function

test.prototype.bind = function() {
    return 'test';
};

console.log(test.bind()); // this does not work as expected -> returns new bound function instead of 'test'. When I do delete Function.prototype.bind, then console.log(test.bind) returns undefined
```

Comment: `test.prototype.bind` adds a method to instances of `test`, ie `new test().bind`. It does not define `test.bind`. In your first case, `test.bind` is directly inherit from `Function.prototype`, not from `test.prototype`.

Comment: As far as I see it is impossible to add a custom method to function prototype chain without modifying the `Function.prototype`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a function `test`. It is a `instanceof Function`, and inherits from `Function.prototype` so that you can call `test.bind` for example.

Then you set the "prototype" property of your function to an object inheriting from `Function.prototype`. That means that all instances of `test` will inherit from that object (and from Function.prototype):

```
var t = new test;
t instanceof test; // => true
t instanceof Function; // => true
```

Then you overwrite the test property on your custom prototype object. You do good to do so, because Function methods should only be called on functions (i.e. callable objects):

```
>>> Function.prototype.bind.call({})
Unhandled Error: Function.prototype.bind: this object not callable
```

In your tests with `console.log` you only apply the Function methods on your `test` function, not on instances of it. Good, because they'd fail. So, I can see no reason why any objects should inherit from `Function` - you can't construct functions that don't inherit directly from `Function`.

Comment: Thanks for complete explanation. As far as I don't want to extend the Function prototype I am about to use some proxy class, though it won't be so elegant... =(