# Define a function with a prototype chain

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an object `X` defined as

```
var X = function () {};
X.prototype.doSomething = function () {};
X.prototype.doSomethingElse = function () {};
```

Is it possible to construct a **function** `f` so that `f instanceof X`?
Note that I must also be able to do `f()` without a `TypeError`.

---

In Mozilla, I can do exactly what I want with `__proto__`:

```
var f = function () {};
f.__proto__ = new X;
```

However, that is (1) nonstandard and (2) deprecated. [MDN's page for `__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto) suggests using `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead, but what I'm really looking for is an `Object.setPrototypeOf` (which doesn't exist, though the idea is brought up in [this bug report](https://bugs.ecmascript.org/show_bug.cgi?id=264)).

A cheap approximation to what I want is

```
var f = function () {};
jQuery.extend(f, new X);
```

Unfortunately, this does not make `f instanceof X` true (nor would I
expect it to!).

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is what is usually called "callable objects". You may want to do a quick search on StackOverflow for that term if it's what you're looking for. Not sure if you're going to find a solution as simple as `__proto__` offers.

Comment: I'm gonna go with "Why?" and "Probably not." on this one.

Comment: @RyanKinal: A use case is shown in the bug report I linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible (in a standard way). Every possibility to create a callable object (i.e., a function) will create one inheriting from `Function.prototype`<sup>1</sup>; and you can't change the `[[prototype]]` of an object afterwards<sup>2</sup>.

See also:

- [create function in javascript with custom prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12443769/1048572)
- [Can you create functions with custom prototypes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16596117/1048572)
- [Is it possible to create a function with another prototype than Function.prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5135326/1048572)
- [Can a JavaScript object have a prototype chain, but also be a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/340383/1048572)
- [Custom prototype chain for a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10597421/1048572)
- [Correct prototype chain for Function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383172/1048572) (for some internals)

<sub>1: OK, ES6 allows us to [subclass `Function`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36871498/1048572). But that's not as useful as it sounds.

2: Since ES6, you can use [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).</sub>

Comment: Why would you want that? And you still can extend Function.prototype.

Comment: While I personally don't have a use case (I was just curious if JavaScript could do that), there is one use case in the bug report I linked in the question.