# JavaScript static inheritance

Tags: javascript

In the code in this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/odirab/6/edit) how do I get MultiPage to inherit the static members of Tool in order that we could write MultiPage.Nullo or MultiPage.datacontext?

Comment: I'm sorry, but why didn't you assign these properties to Tool.prototype as well?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to inherit static members, there's nothing for it but to copy the properties of Tool onto MultiPage. It's easy enough with jQuery or Underscore:

```
$.extend(MultiPage, Tool);
_.extend(MultiPage, Tool);
```

You can easily make your own `extend` if you don't want to add any utility libraries:

```
function extend(target, source) {
    for(var key in source) {
        if (source.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== 'prototype') {
            target[key] = source[key];
        }
    }
}
```

The reason you can't simply inherit static properties is that constructor functions cannot themselves have an internal class other than `Function`. So a constructor function's `prototype` (not its own `prototype` property, but the `Function.prototype` which directly extends the constructor function object) is always `Function.prototype`, shared amongst every function under the same global scope.

#### Update

As of 2016, major browsers support [Object.setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf). However, as you can see in the linked documentation, this function breaks all kinds of engine optimizations. I do not recommend using this, since you can usually structure your program to avoid its drawbacks.

Comment: Absolute top grade A answer.  Complete, concise explanation of both solution and background, thanks.

Comment: Not correct, you can very well do `Object.setPrototypeOf(MultiPage, Tool)`

Comment: @felixfbecker Support for [Object.setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) was awful three years ago when this answer was posted, and even now, it breaks all kinds of engine optimizations. Not recommended if you can just structure your program to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get MultiPage to inherit the static members of Tool

This is impossible. A function [can only inherit from `Function.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11003365/1048572), and nothing in between.

However, there is no need to do that. [JavaScript is no class-based language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418980/1048572), and there is a better solution for your actual problem. You haven't told us about your usecase yet, but standard solutions would be putting the property on the `prototype` object or just accessing it as `Tool.datacontext` even from a `Multipage`.