# Can you create functions with custom prototypes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, customization, prototype

First of all, I *don't* want to add methods to `Function.prototype`. Doing that would make them available for *all* functions and that's not what I'm looking for.

In JavaScript you can create objects with custom prototypes like this:

```
function CustomObj() {}
CustomObj.prototype = {};
CustomObj.prototype.sayFoo = function () { return 'foo' };

var myCustomObj = new CustomObj(); //=> returns an object: {}
myCusomObj.sayFoo(); //=> 'foo'
```

You can also create array-like objects with custom prototypes like this:

```
function CustomArr() {}
CustomArr.prototype = [];
CustomObj.prototype.sayFoo = function () { return 'foo' };

var myCustomArr = new CustomArr(); //=> returns an ordered object: []
myCustomArr.sayFoo(); //=> 'foo'
```

What I'd like to do is use some kind of constructor to create a function with its own custom prototype in the same way. However, the following does not work:

```
function CustomFn() {}
CustomFn.prototype = function () {};
CustomFn.prototype.sayFoo = function () { return 'foo' };

var myCustomFn = new CustomFn(); //=> PROBLEM! returns an object: {}
myCustomFn.sayFoo(); //=> 'foo'

// ^^ Here, the prototype was applied but the output was not a function.
myCustomFn(); //=> TypeError: object is not a function
```

So is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

### UPDATE

Maybe there's another way I could be asking this question that would make it a little clearer.

There's a problem with the idea of a closure:

```
function makeFn() {
  var output = function () { /* do some stuff */ };
  output.foo = function () { /* do some stuff */ };
  return output;
}
var specialFn = makeFn();
```

Essentially, this technique gives me what I want. However, the problem is that every time I call `makeFn`, `output.foo` has to be created as a totally independent function that takes up its own memory. Gross. So I could move that method out of the closure:

```
var protoMethods = {
  "foo" : function () { /* do some stuff */ }
};
function makeFn() {
  var output = function () { /* do some stuff */ };
  for (var i in protoMethods) {
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(protoMethods, i) &&
      (output[i] = protoMethods[i]);
  }
  return output;
}
var specialFn = makeFn();
```

But now I have to manually do an iteration every time I call `makeFn` which would be less efficient than if I could just assign `protoMethods` to be the prototype of `output`. So, with this new update, any ideas?

Comment: I tried that too, when working on [V library](http://metadea.de/V/). So no, using the new operator, you can only create new "object"s, but not new "function object"s. However you can use a constructor function both as a constructor and as a function!

Comment: That's disappointing. There would be so many really interesting and creative applications of this kind of technique if we had it. Seems like it should go hand in hand with the concept of a closure. Sure, I can return a function with methods attached, but that means every time I invoke the closure I'm doing a less-optimized iteration, and creating totally new functions every time.

Answer (score 5):

It is a tricky thing indeed, more complicated than it should be if the language was designed well...

Basically, you just can't do it cleanly in current versions. Objects other than functions can not be callable.

In future Javascript versions, you can do it with a "proxy" object that can define a "call" handler. But it is still way too complicated and contrived in my opinion.

Another way to go about it is to make your object a real function, not a custom object. Then try to set its `__proto__`, which is non-standard yet but works in most modern browsers, except Opera and IE 8 or less. Also maybe set its `constructor` property for faking `instanceof` checks... such hacks are quite tricky though and results will vary a lot with environments.

The following example works fine on my Firefox:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q3422/2/

```
function MyFun() {
    if (!this || this==window) {
        return new MyFun();
    }

    var f = function() {
        return "thanks for calling!";
    }
    f.__proto__ = MyFun.prototype;
    f.constructor = MyFun;

    return f;
}

MyFun.prototype = {
    foo: function() {
        return "foo:" + this();
    },
    __proto__: Function.prototype
};

var f = new MyFun();
alert("proto method:"+f.foo()); // try our prototype methods
alert("function method:"+f.call()); // try standard function methods
alert("function call:"+f()); // try use as a function
alert('typeof:' + typeof f); // "function", not "object". No way around it in current js versions
alert('is MyFun:' + (f instanceof MyFun)); // true
alert('is Function:' + (f instanceof Function)); // true
```

Just wanted to add that you should not be worried about "copying" functions to each instance of your objects. The function itself is an object, so is never really copied, nor is it recompiled or anything. It does not waste memory, except for the function object reference itself and any closure variables.

Iterating over the prototype to copy it should not concern you as well, I guess you will not have a gazillion methods.

So your own last solution is probably the best if you need to support environments where **proto** is not settable, and you are not worried that your prototype might get extended after some objects already got created and they may not pick up the changes.

Comment: *"Also maybe set its `constructor` property for faking `instanceof` checks"* The `constructor` property has nothing to do with `instanceof`.

Answer (score 2):

You're at the heart of what inheritance in JavaScript is all about. Yes, since prototypes are objects, you'll want to set the prototype of CustomFn to an object instead of a function.

But that object can come from another function:

```
function ParentFn() {}
function CustomFn() {}
CustomFn.prototype = Object.create(ParentFn.prototype);
CustomFn.prototype.sayFoo = fun ...
```

If you don't have ES5 or a polyfill:

```
CustomFn.prototype = (function() {
                          function F(){}
                          F.prototype = ParentFn.prototype;
                          return new F();
                      }());
```

Some may tell you just to do the following but the above way is better:

```
CustomFn.prototype = new ParentFn();
```

Comment: This doesn't make `new CustomFn` be a function

Answer (score 0):

I tried that too, when working on [V library](https://web.archive.org/web/20150913025831/http://metadea.de/V/). I wanted to override the Function constructor to enforce a restricted syntax of constructor functions, that I'm calling "class functions" (and I'm confident to do so).

Answer is no, using the new operator you can only create new "object"s, but not new "function object"s.

However you can use a constructor function both as a constructor and as a function!

```
var CustomFn = function () {
  if (this instanceof CustomFn) {
    // here we are 'new CustomFn()'
  }
  else {
    // here we are 'CustomFn()' or 'CustomFn.call()'
  }
};
```

Or as I believe is the better concept, to do the function in first place and then let the constructor go:

```
var CustomFn = function () {
  if (!(this instanceof CustomFn)) { // functioning
    // here we are 'CustomFn()' or 'CustomFn.call()'
    return new CustomFn(); // or return undefined or throw
  }

  // constructing
  // here we are 'new CustomFn()'

  // BaseCustomFn.call(this);
};
```

Comment: can you give me an example of how you might call that and actually hit the first condition? i'm having a hard time conceptualizing for some reason.