# Prototype property for a function

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, prototype

I'm trying to get this:

```
a = new Foo(name); // a is function
a(); // returns a result
a.set(); // returns another result
```

I've implemented above like that:

```
function Foo (name) = {
  val = name;
  ret = function () { return val; }
  ret.set = function (v) { return val = v; }
  return ret;
}
```

Then, for multiple instances of Foo I'd like not to create method 'set', but share it through prototype property. However, all experiments I did have no effect. It works only on objects, not on functions. Even the code below doesn't work:

```
foo = function () { return 'a'; }
foo.foo = function ()  { return 'foo'; }
foo.prototype.bar = function ()  { return 'bar'; }

foo(); // a
foo.foo(); // foo
foo.bar(); // Uncaught TypeError: Object function () { return 'a'; } has no method 'bar'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to add a property to only some functions via the prototype chain. Functions have one object in their prototype chain, which is `Function.prototype`. There is no way to create functions which have other `[[Prototype]]`s.

The closest you can come to what you want are these two examples:

**Your solution**

```
function Foo (name) = {
  val = name;
  ret = function () { return val; }
  ret.set = function (v) { return val = v; }
  return ret;
}
```

**Changing Function.prototype**

```
Function.prototype.set = function (v) { return this.val = v; };
function Foo (name){
  ret = function () { return this.val; }
  ret.val = name;
  return ret;
}

var f = new Foo('myfunc');
f.set('myval');
console.log(f.val);
```

I would strongly recommend the first solution, because in the second one, every function shares the `set` property/method. Changing predefined Prototypes is usually frowned upon unless it's to port functionality from newer editions of the language.

Comment: Yes, I've found [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596117/can-you-create-functions-with-custom-prototypes-in-javascript). And the answer is similar to - there is now way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In your last example `foo` does **not** have the function `bar`, only it's prototype does.

Therefore only a `foo` object would have the function `bar`

---

So you *could* do this:

```
foo = function () { return 'a'; }
foo.foo = function ()  { return 'foo'; }
foo.prototype.bar = function ()  { return 'bar'; }

var f = new foo(); // [object]
f.foo(); // TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'foo'
f.bar(); // bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foo = function (name){
      this.name = name;
    }
foo.prototype.set = function(name){ return this.name = name; }

var f = new foo('yourName');
alert(f.name);
f.set('yourNameEdited');
alert(f.name);
```

Here's [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/wn93C/)

Comment: Yes, but the function itself `f()` doesn't work. That was the goal.