# What is an idiomatic way to put fields/attributes on a function in modern javascript (es5 or later)?

Tags: javascript

I would like to do something like this:

```js
"use strict"; // on by default in my babel setup
function create_func(some, params) {
    var func = otherstuff => {
        console.log("inner", some, otherstuff);
        return 4;
    };
    /*
      something here, such as:
      func.params = params;
    */ 
    return func;
}
var f = create_func(1,2);
console.log(f.params); // should print 2
var returnval = f(3); // should print "inner", 1, 3
console.log(returnval); // should print 4
```

This is related to eg how `jQuery()` is a function, but `jQuery.ajax()` is also an accessible function.

What would be the ideal way to do this in ES5, ES2015, or later?

Here's a question that asks how to do something similar to this, but without the constraint that it be modern JS: [Can you create functions with custom prototypes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596117/can-you-create-functions-with-custom-prototypes-in-javascript/16596366#16596366)

Comment: Just assign `params` property to `func`, like `func.params = params`. What exactly here's wrong to you?

Comment: Functions are data and they are also objects in JavaScript. Learning how functions work is really what you need to investigate. This is not a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh, that's unexpected, it works when I run it in the browser. I'll have to edit the question, because the real problem seems to be something very different from this simply being not allowed. thanks!

Comment: Sorry, what's wrong with what you have? The language hasn't changed that much since jQuery was created. At best you have `class`es now, where you could make the constructor be the function call, and it could have all the static properties you want...

Comment: It appears that I already had working code, and I'm now confused as to why I was getting errors at all.

Comment: voted to close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding custom properties to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588563/adding-custom-properties-to-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

If your function is supposed to be a class with static properties, use `class` syntax.

Otherwise, you can use `Object.assign`:

```
function create_func(some, params) {
    return Object.assign(otherstuff => {
        console.log("inner", some, otherstuff);
        return 4;
    }, {params});
}
```

Of course simple assignment continues to work - there's no new syntax to create properties on function objects specifically.

> Can you create functions with custom prototypes in JavaScript?

If that is what you are after (not just giving the function object custom *properties*), you can [subclass `Function` since ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36871299/1048572) but it's not exactly convenient.