# Node.js Connect createServer code

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-connect

I'm reading Node.js Connect version 2.15.0:

```
/**
 * Create a new connect server.
 *
 * @return {Function}
 * @api public
 */

function createServer() {
  function app(req, res, next){ app.handle(req, res, next); }
  utils.merge(app, proto);
  utils.merge(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
  app.route = '/';
  app.stack = []; 
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
    app.use(arguments[i]);
  }
  return app;
};
```

A few questions:

1. `app.handle` seems to be provided in proto, since there is
   `app.handle` defined in proto.js. So, this is a use of a closure,
   and `app.handle` is defined not at the time Node parses `function
   app()` but later on in the code? Also `app` itself is defined
   in..uh..`function app()`. The code seems funny to me.
2. When is `function app()` invoked? All I know create server creates
       the server. So when would I be invoking that function and how? Do I
       do something like:

   ```
   app = createServer()
   app.listen(3000)
   app(req, res, next)
   ```
3. utils.merge() simply says

   ```
   exports.merge = function(a, b){ 
     if (a && b) {
       for (var key in b) {
         a[key] = b[key];
       }   
     }
     return a;
   };
   ```

   Is that a common practice to do instead of inheritance or what? It looks like `mixin` to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. `app.handle` seems to be provided in proto, since there is
>      `app.handle` defined in proto.js. So, this is a use of a closure,
>      and `app.handle` is defined not at the time Node parses `function app()`
>      but later on in the code? Also `app` itself is defined
>      in..uh..`function app()`. The code seems funny to me.

Yes, `app.handle` comes from `proto`. But no, accessing `app` inside the `app` function is not a closure, a function is available by its name in all function declarations.

> 2. When is `function app()` invoked? All I know `createServer` creates
>      the server. So when would I be invoking that function and how?

The [connect docs](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) use this example code:

```
var app = connect();
…
http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

You can see that `connect` (which is the `createServer` function you posted) does create the `app`, which is passed as a handler to the actual http server.

> 3. Is `utils.merge()` a common practice instead of inheritance or what? It looks like `mixin` to me.

Yes, `merge` does mixin one object into the other. This is done to extend the function object `app` with all the necessary methods. It is necessary because it is impossible to [Define a function with a prototype chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11003154/1048572) in a standard way. They might have used something along these lines as well:

```
app.__proto__ = utils.merge(Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype), proto);
```

but then `app` wouldn't any longer be `instanceof Function`; and have no function methods.

Comment: Thanks for 1. I need to chew a bit on 3. For 2, `var app` is a result for the `createServer()` function I posted. How does `http.createServer()` execute the line `app.handle(req, res, next)` inside the `createServer()` I posted?

Comment: `http.createServer(…)` is equivalent to `(new http.Server).addListener('request', …)`. [Hunt down](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js) where/how this event is emitted yourself.